# Config File Process in Python and C++

Tags: c++, python, configuration

There are a lot of questions and answers on how to parse/create config files in python and C++ individually. In my case, I have one single config file and need to be processed (read/write) by both python and C++.

In python world, ConfigParser is popular; while in C++, libconfig looks nice. But they are using different formats. What I am looking for is a stone being able to kill two birds at the same time. :)

Comment: Just write your own? Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/166663), [nor is it a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/166663). If you're attempting to write this common-format generator/parser yourself and have a _specific_ question about that, that's where SO becomes appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious solution that comes to mind is to go with something along the lines of YAML or JSON which you should find support for across many languages.